# Access and change size of Components placed on a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, jdialog

I created a **modal** JDialog (to be correct, a children of JDialog) and set it visible when the user clicks on a JButton on a JFrame. To make sure the content on the JDialog is vertically centered I've overridden the *setVisible()* method and do some operations before calling `super.setVisible(true)`. The problem here is that no component, that's placed on the dialog, does have an other size than 0 before calling *setVisible(true)* if the dialog is set to be modal. Also *setVisible()* does block the execution.

Any suggestions/tips how to bypass/fix this issue?

Sample code:

```
public class SampleDialog extends JDialog {

    protected JPanel contentPane;

    public SampleDialog() {
        super();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setModal(true);

        JPanel headerPane = new JPanel();
        headerPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(headerPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel footerPane = new JPanel();
        footerPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(footerPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Code"));
        contentPane.add(new JTextField());
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        contentPane.add(new JPasswordField());
        contentPane.add(new JButton("Login"));
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        /*
         * Get total height of all components added to 'contentPane'
         * Place Box.createVerticalStrut() before and after the 'contentPane' components,
         * so the input fields look like they are centered vertically
         * !!! Cannot determine size of any component because it is not rendered
         */
        super.setVisible(b);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show pertinent code, preferably as a valid [mcve] and perhaps an image of what you're wanting and what you're getting. Please note that the code should be posted in  your question as code-formatted text and not in a link. Good luck!

Comment: Also, your question suggests that you may be trying to go around Swing's natural sizing and positioning of components, and it's usually better to work with the system rather than against it -- but I can't tell for sure without your [mcve]. Also, yes, nothing in a GUI sizes until the GUI has been rendered. `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` will render things for you. And also, yes, a *modal* dialog will block the calling code once it has been displayed.

Answer (score 2):

> to make sure the content on the JDialog is vertically centered i've overriden the setVisible()

You should NOT be overriding setVisible() for this.

To center the component use an appropriate layout manager.

For example to center components vertically and horizontally you can just use a GridBagLayout:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setLayout( new GrigBagLayout() );

JPanel panel = new JPanel(...);
panel.add(...);
dialog.add(panel, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MigLayout` manager to easily create your intended layout:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/*
 * Centering components on screen.
 * Author Jan Bodnar
 * Website zetcode.com
 */
class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    public MyDialog() {

        initDialog();
    }

    private void initDialog() {

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Code");
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(15);

        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Password");
        JPasswordField field2 = new JPasswordField(15);        

        JButton btn = new JButton("Login");

        createLayout(lbl1, field1, lbl2, field2, btn);

        setTitle("Login");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setModal(true);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap, align 50% 50%", "[center]"));

        add(arg[0]);
        add(arg[1]);
        add(arg[2]);
        add(arg[3]);
        add(arg[4]);

        pack();
    }
}

public class MigLayoutCenterEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutCenterEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

        JButton btn = new JButton("Show dialog");
        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

            JDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        });

        pnl.add(btn);
        add(pnl);

        setSize(400, 300);
        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutCenterEx ex = new MigLayoutCenterEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the code example]